# HCL Notes internet address not found in the secondary address book

Tags: email-server, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I have an issue which I can't get resolved. I hope you can help me out.

I have setup a secondary NAB in HCL Notes/Domino v12.0.2 which is mainly being used for web users to authenticate. I have setup DIRECTORY ASSISTANCE, defined a new domain and enabled all settings.

[Screenshot DA settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72sk3.png)

Persons who are in this secondary directory can authenticate fine. No problem at all! But when a mail is sent from my web application (via an agent), the internet address of this person is not being retrieved. Domino appends the main domain at the end of the user name as sender. It looks like John Doe%DOMAINNAME

If I move this person document to the main Names.nsf, this works fine! Then the sender of the email is the internet address which is specified in the person document.

What am I missing here? Did I forget to configure something so Domino will also check this secondary address book to define the email address of the sender? Since moving the person document to names.nsf makes it all work it seems like Domino is not checking the second addressbook. However authentication works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The product documentation has a extensive chapter on how HCL Domino lookups or creates the sender address at https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/12.0.2/admin/conf_settinguphowaddressesareresolvedoninboundandoutb_c.html 
As this works for your "regular" users, this seems to be set up correctly.

Without seeing you actual agent code, I can only guess, but I would assume that you are not explicitly setting a sender address at all (which you should). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676368/lotusscript-from-address-when-sending-email-as-web-user for examples.